# Index of dispersion with approximate distribution

Tags: probability, estimation, variance, bounds, probability-inequalities

I have an unknown discrete probability distribution $D$ ($D$ is a probability mass function), defined on an interval $[a,b]$ ($a>0$) and an estimation $\hat{D}$ such that, for all $t\in[a,b]$, 
$$(1-\varepsilon)D(t)\le\hat{D}(t)\le(1+\varepsilon)D(t)$$ 
for some fixed $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$. Moreover $\hat{D}$ is actually a distribution on $[a,b]$ too.

Can anything be said about how well does the index of dispersion $\hat{\sigma}^2/\hat{\mu}$ of $\hat{D}$ approximate  the index of dispersion $\sigma^2 / \mu$ of $D$?

Note that it is easy to show that $(1-\varepsilon)\mu\le \hat{\mu}\le (1+\varepsilon)\mu$, but I'm stuck at showing a bound for the deviation between the variances $\hat{\sigma}^2$ and $\sigma^2$

Comment: (1) Does "$D$" stand for the probability mass function or for the cumulative distribution function? (2) Presumably $a\ge 0$, for otherwise the index of dispersion makes little sense.

Comment: 1) for the probability mass function. 2) $a\ge 0$, yes. (Question edited to report this clarifications)